# How to loop through an document saving every results that applies

Tags: python

i have a document containing a dict of results, what i want to do is loop through the  document and save each result that is right

this is my current code which works fine but will only the return the first result

```
#Fetch router descriptors based on a given flag
def getHSDirFlag():
   for r in router.itervalues():
        if 'HSDir' in r['flags']:
            return r
   return None
```

i have tried :

```
def getHSDirFlag():
   HSDirList =()
   for r in router.itervalues():
        if 'HSDir' in r['flags']:
            HSDirList += r
        return HSDirList
   return None
```

but get the error TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "dict") to tuple

what is the best data type to save a dict to and how can i loop through the doc finding every result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, why would you call a variable `HSDirList` and make it a `tuple`, *not a `list`*?!

Second, why `return` the "list" *inside* the `for` loop, then tack a `return None` (which will *never* be reached) to the end of the function?

Try:

```
def getHSDirFlag(router):
   HSDirList = [] # an actual list
   for r in router.itervalues():
       if 'HSDir' in r['flags']:
           HSDirList.append(r) # add to the list
   return HSDirList # return the list
```

Note that the `return` is *outside* the `for` loop, so doesn't happen until you've iterated over all `itervalues`. Also, `router` is now an argument to the function, rather than relying on scope.

Finally, you should read and consider implementing the [Python style guide, PEP-0008](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 0):

you can save your dictionaries in `JSON` file ! in this code you have a tuple and you want to concatenate dictionaries on it but i suggest you use `JSON` for saving dicts !

this code is for saving a json file :

```
import json
with open('data.json', 'wb') as fp:
    json.dump(data, fp)
```

and this one for load

```
with open('data.json', 'rb') as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)
```

read more at https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html